# Combining 2 Large Text Files

Tags: powershell, command-line, command

I'm trying to combine 2 large text files in Windows 10 (200mb each) but it seems that my usual method Command Window >> Copy *.txt Combine.txt doesn't work. The outputted file is the size of only one of the files so I'm assuming that method doesn't work for large files. Is there another way I can do easily this?

Comment: Will `add-content` do what you want to do?  `gci *.txt | % { Add-Content $_ Combine.txt -encoding Byte }` or something similar

Comment: `COPY *.txt Combine.txt` should have worked. Are you sure that both .txt files are in the directory? You could also try `COPY file1.txt+file2.txt Combine.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply append it

```
Get-content file1.txt | out-file c:\combined.txt -append
Get-content file2.txt | out-file c:\combined.txt -append
```

A much faster method is .net ReadLines

```
[System.io.file]::readlines("c:\file1.txt") | out-file c:\combined.txt -append
[System.io.file]::readlines("c:\file2.txt") | out-file c:\combined.txt -append
```

Answer (score 1):

If the destination file does not already exist or already contains content, you’ll want to issue the New-Item command first.  If you know it doesn’t exist or is empty, you can skip that line, below.

```
New-Item -ItemType file ".\combined_files.txt" –force

Get-Content .\file?.txt | Add-Content .\combined_files.txt
```